# Why wait to delete a question after it is closed

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-delete, rate-limiting

I admit I posted a bad question and when I try to delete it I get the message "To allow for possible reopening, you may delete the message in 2 days". What's the point of this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Closed questions are *not* dead, they can be re-opened if the community deems that the closing was incorrect or if they are improved, and it makes sense to allow for some time for enough people to examine it before you can delete it.

Comment: Additionally members of the communitte may want to improve the question, even if the OP has lost interest in it.